# POST запрос к API Яндекс Дистрибуции через Python (библиотека Requests)

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь послать POST запрос по API Яндекс Дистрибуции через Python библиотеку Requests, но по какой то причине получаю ошибку, что я пытаюсь послать GET запрос.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
ReportsURL = 'https://distribution.yandex.net/api/v2/statistics/basic/report?lang=en'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8', 'Authorization': 'OAuth %key%'}
body = {
  "period": ["yesterday"],
  "dimensions": [
    "soft_id",
    "vid",
    "pack_id",
    "currency_id"
  ],
  "measures": [
    "setups",
    "searches",
    "partner_all",
    "partner_activations",
    "partner_setups",
    "partner_direct"
  ]
}
r3 = requests.post(ReportsURL, data=body, headers=headers)
r3.text
```

И получаю вот такой ответ:

```
'{"result":"error","data":{"description":"Method \\"GET\\" not allowed.","message":"method_not_allowed"}}'
```

Может быть кто то сможет подсказать в чем проблема? Такое ощущение, что то очевидное упускаю.

Comment: Могу предположить что body скорее всего JSON. А на то скорее всего есть ответ в докумментаций по API. Но нам смертным туда не попасть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что в конце урла не было не было слеша и он проделывал редирект

```
ReportsURL = 'https://distribution.yandex.net/api/v2/statistics/basic/report/?lang=en'
```

Должно быть вот так. Отследил с помощью библиотек http.client и logging. Если вдруг у вас похожая проблема, то добавьте

```
import logging
import http.client as http_client
```

И после body

```
# These two lines enable debugging at httplib level (requests->urllib3->http.client)
# You will see the REQUEST, including HEADERS and DATA, and RESPONSE with HEADERS but without DATA.
# The only thing missing will be the response.body which is not logged.



http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению я не могу получить доступ к API Яндекс.Дистрибьюции, но из очевидного, на что следует обратить внимание, это то, что метод GET не подразумевает наличие тела запроса. Технически это возможно, но большинство библиотек и API его просто не примут. К тому же вы используете `requests.post()` вместо предполагаемого `requests.get()`. Убедитесь, что вы действительно должны послать GET запрос с телом. Дополнительную информацию пишите в комментарии

Comment: А я как раз пытаюсь использовать именно POST, но по какой то причине получаю ответ, будто я пытаюсь использовать GET

Comment: "очевидное упускаю" у вас в headers ясно написано  'content-type': 'application/json', body у вас должен быть в формате JSON.

Comment: подключил import json и с помощью body = json.dumps(body, indent=4) поменял формат, но ответ продолжает тот же самый приходить